# PHP if else condition not getting applied as per desire result

Tags: php, mysql

I am pulling some data from mysql database into php
this is tobe displayed on screen via tables in php
one of the field is too long, so I want to make that particulate field scroll (marquee) only if char is more than 20.

I tried below code, which only takes one condition and applies to all the cells
Even tried using without TD, but result is same.

```
if (strlen($row['TName']) >= 20 ) 
    {
    echo "<td style='font-size:55pt' max-width='15%' align='left' class='Info'> <marquee>" . $row['TName'] . "</marquee></td>";
} 
else {
    echo "<td style='font-size:55pt' max-width='15%' align='left' class='Info'>" . $row['TName'] . "</td>";
}
```

This should be individually applied to each cell.

EDIT - 
I am pulling, TNumber, TName, TTime, TPF
All fields are having limited number of characters
Only TName got from 12 to 30 character in them. 
some TNames are as below

```
    Chennai SF Express  
Bangalore Chennai super fast express  
Chatrapati Shivaji Terminals Gujarat express.
Kurla Express
```

Comment: https://3v4l.org/8EvBq Works for me. Just note that you're checking TrainName but outputting TName

Comment: Edited the code, but still, only one of the condition is applied to all the $row['TName']

Comment: Can you show some sample data, and what is being output? Just [edit] your post with that information.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with the marquee. I suggest using css style overflow: scroll;, try one of these for the else condition:

```
echo "<td style='text-overflow: ellipsis;white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; font-size:55pt' max-width='15%' align='left' class='Info'>" . $row['TName'] . "</td>";


echo "<td style='overflow: scroll; font-size:55pt' max-width='15%' align='left' class='Info'>" . $row['TName'] . "</td>";
```

Comment: Actual data length seen on screen and given by strlen were different, due to which above mention if else condition was not working, by echo strlen of each TName got to know the actual length.  And by increasing condition number got the desire results.